# QTableView: How can i use clicked() signal correctly to get index of selected item?

Tags: c++, qt, click, signals

I am having a delete button in every row. I am trying to use `clicked()` SIGNAL of `QTableview` to get the current index and then do something accordingly, but this slot is not called in this case. For some reason it doesn't work, am I making some mistake in connecting `clicked()` SIGNAL?

```
    void MyClass::myFunction()
    {
            ComboBoxItemDelegate* myDelegate;
            myDelegate = new ComboBoxItemDelegate();
            model = new STableModel(1, 8, this);
            filterSelector->tableView->setModel(model);
            filterSelector->tableView->setItemDelegate(myDelegate);
            connect(filterSelector->tableView, SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex&)), this, SLOT(slotHandleDeleteButton(const QModelIndex&)));
            exec();
    }

    void MyClass::slotHandleDeleteButton(const QModelIndex& index)
    {
        if(index.column() == 8)
            model->removeRow(index.row());
    }
```

Comment: Is `MyClass` derived from the `SFilterEditor` ?

Comment: I suppose it works for all columns except for that one with the buttons. Right?

Comment: The problem is that you click not on the table view row, but rather on a delete button. You need to connect `clicked()` signal of rather button than table view.

Comment: @Tomas No, it's not working for any column.

Comment: @vahancho i tried that but i faced few issues in that approach. If i use clicked() signal of button, then i cannot pass the index in the corresponding slot because clicked signal for qpushbutton is of following form:
void QAbstractButton::clicked ( bool checked = false ) and i need index to identify the row. Using QSignalMapper is not an option because it will bind the button to a fixed value.

Comment: @wazza, there several ways to solve it: 1) Make your own button class (derived from QPushButton) with a custom signal, 2) Store the mapping between button and its row number, etc.

Comment: yeah i thought about using a custom signal but then i switched to this approach because i can use it in few other places.

Comment: @vahancho can you please provide a solution to this issue using above mentioned approach ?

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions can look like this:

```
class Button : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Button(int row, QWidget *parent = 0) : QPushButton(parent), m_row(row)
    {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onClicked()));
    }

signals:
    void clicked(int row);

private slots:
    void onClicked()
    {
        emit clicked(m_row);
    }
private:
    int m_row;
};
```

`Button` class contains a custom signal `clicked(int)` with the row number as an argument. To use it in your table view you need to do:

```
Button *btn = new Button(rowNumber, this);
connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked(int)), this, SLOT(onButtonClicked(int)));
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I tried this but there is an issue in this approach. 

@vahancho Since these delete buttons remove entire row, so when 3rd row out of 5 row is removed then index of delete buttons in lower rows(4th & 5th) is not updated. i mean 4th row will now be 3rd row but index stored for it's delete button will be 4th which will cause inconsistency among delete button index and index of row(rowPosition).